# Write a function substr(stringA,StringB) that returns true if StringA is a subset of StringB,and false otherwise

Tags: python

Actually, i can use the build in function to do it, but the questions requires me to use loops, any helps? i dont have any idea about using loop to solve it.

Comment: str(a) = input("Enter something:")
str(b) = input("Enter something:")
for i in range str(b):
    if i in str(a):
        print(true)

print(false)

Comment: Put that code in your original question so it can be formatted properly.

Comment: Read through the tutorial in the documentation, there is a section on flow control and loops - that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

> the questions requires me to use loops

```
def isin(stringa, stringb):
    while 7:
        return stringa in stringb
```

Comment: I would have went with 42 for my loop. But that's just me.

Comment: 7 improves the performance because the interpreter has to read one byte less.

Comment: You're on fire tonight.